# Finding Cache configuration

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

If you're given the hit rate for a cache config (associativity, set size, block size and capacity) how do you reverse engineer this to find out the configuration if another hit rate was given?

so if i say the hit rate is 82% how would i estimate the cache config of this? I've tried doing trial error by plugging in values for C= ABS but I cant seem to land on the accurate hit ratio itself

so for a hit rate of 84% I tried with A=2, B=64 and Set = 8. The code is a transpose code for double type. Im not sure how to approach it

Comment: You need to know the access pattern in detail if you want to figure out anything based on it and hit-rate.  Probably also the eviction algorithm if conflict-misses could be happening. 
 (pseudo-LRU or LFU are common in practice, true LRU takes more bits but you might see it in a theoretical homework exercise.)

Comment: I was working with a matrices transpose code with true LRU. the code is                                                                for (i=0; i<N; i++)                                                         
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)                                                        
          B[i*N+j] = A[j*N+i];

Comment: Oh, so a naive transpose, not recursive cache-blocked.  But you haven't said what `N` is.  Perhaps you're supposed to be able to work that out as well from the hit rate for a given cache config?

Comment: oops sorry, N is 4. when N is 4 the cache hit rate is 84.375% and when N>=8 the hit rate is 43.75%.Using this we have to figure out the cache config

Comment: Ok, so [edit] your question to include all that necessary info.  Also, your attempt so far, e.g. a trace of the memory access pattern to look for accesses which are offset from each other by a multiple of 256 or some other power of 2 and thus would alias the same set for some cache geometries but not others.  Homework questions requite an attempt.  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I did attempt the question. I calculated the total cache accesses and used the percentage to determine that there were 5 misses. After that I tried trial and error with associativity as 2 block size 64 and set 1. The number of misses was too less. I then tried associativity of 4 and the misses were too high. I wanted know if there was an alternative and faster approach.

Comment: So [edit] your question with details of your attempt and what you've figured out so far.  No, there's no simple straightforward formula that I'm aware of, unless perhaps that specific transpose algorithm happens to line up with how set-associative caches work and lead to something less complicated that it looks like it would be to reverse-engineer and manually simulate for different cases.